# Why does a level of indirection allow omitting `mut`?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why doesn't the param to `write1` need to be mut? It passes the value directly to another function that requires `mut` access.

Any justification for the need for `mut` in `write1` seems it would apply to `write2`, but the compiler doesn't agree:

```rs
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let out = &mut std::io::stdout();
    write1(out)
}

fn write1(mut out: impl Write) {      // `mut` not required. Adding `mut` produces warning: "variable does not need to be mutable"
    write2(out)
}

fn write2(mut out: impl Write) {  // `mut` required! Otherwise error "cannot borrow `out` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable"
    writeln!(out, "hi").unwrap();
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db9b506599be86acfd26cff3f02eba3c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `write1`, you're not mutating `out`, you're giving it (moving it) to `write2`, just like the `main` moves it to `write1`.

`write2` is maybe clearer like this:

```rust
fn write2(out: impl Write) {
    let mut out = out;
    writeln!(out, "hi").unwrap();
}
```

It would be very different with references. In this case you'd have, as you intuited, to propagate the mut:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut out = &mut std::io::stdout();
    write1(&mut out)
}

fn write1(out: &mut impl Write) {
    write2(out)
}

fn write2(out: &mut impl Write) {
    writeln!(out, "hi").unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `&mut` is easy to understand, but I have trouble putting into words what `mut` means in parameters and `let`s. afaict the Rust Book never explains `mut` patterns and the Rust Reference doesn't either. Is `mut` in patterns explained anywhere?
The closest I could find is https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns, but this only explains the syntax.

Comment: "mut" doesn't mean the same thing in `mut` and `&mut`. In the first case, you may mutate the value. In the second case, you have an *exclusive* reference, which makes all other references impossible while it's alive. Does that help fixing your intuition ?

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped sort out my intuition and answers my original question. That said, I'm not confident I can define `mut` in identifier patterns, and am looking for a definition–if there isn't one already in the docs I'm hoping to add such a definition: 

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90605